# Passing Dates as Query String Parameters to SSRS reports, without being affected by Server Date Settings

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am passing Date Parameters to **SSRS** reports, from the **Query string**, for example `http://ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/MyReport&MyDataStart=06/01/2013` (This Date is the first of June 2013). My problem is that the Report server is interpreting the Dates passed based on his Date Settings. On my local server, the dates are being interpreted as 'MM/dd/yyyy', while on the Client Server, the dates are interpreted as 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

Is there a way that I can pass the dates without being affected by the Server Date Settings? Something like the "**Invariant Culture**" in .net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass your date to the report in this format;

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```